# How to make sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" permanent in MySQL my.cnf

Tags: mysql

### UPDATE FIXED 1/18/15

After we recently updated to MySQL 5.6.27 (from the Ubuntu repo), this option now works. So this appears to have been a problem with the previous version of MySQL.

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

With a new upgrade to MySQL (5.6.20), updates and inserts fail unless I set sql-mode to NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.

Thanks to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html), I can run the following from mysql terminal and that fixes the problem (temporarily):

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`
```

But the next time MySQL restarts, these settings are lost.

So I have tried to make that permanent by editing /etc/mysql/my.cnf (on my standard server running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS), and adding the config settings that the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) says should be added:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

### Alternative Syntaxes for Testing

Just for testing purposes, I have also tried the following formats (which do not cause errors when restarting MySQL, but they do not affect the setting).

```
# dash no quotes
sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
# underscore no quotes
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
# underscore and quotes
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Nothing works. After restart this setting is lost and I have to run the commands manually again from mysql terminal to make saving work again.

### Alternative Locations

- I know /etc/mysql/my.cnf is being referenced because we have replication defined in this file, and that is working.
- There is not another identical setting in this file that is overwriting it.

I get a list of the config files that are being referenced by running this from the command line:

```
mysqld --help --verbose
```

I see a line that reads:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

This is the default location it "looks" for files, it doesn't mean that it actually found a file there, e.g. my server doesn't have `/etc/my.cnf`, `/usr/etc/my.cnf` or `~/.my.cnf`.

So it looks like my config in /etc/mysql/my.cnf is the only file mysql is referencing, and therefore this setting is not being overwritten.

### Logical Conclusion of Testing

Logically then, it seems the syntax is not correct or is being ignored for some other reason. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not a big mysql guru, but also the client has its own section in configuration file, could it be that the client config is rewriting the server default?

Comment: Thx, this solved my problem in homebrew osx mysql

sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

https://gist.github.com/fhferreira/dd8a2a24000a562c87ab

Comment: NOTE above, this was a bug that was fixed in our recent update to MySQL 5.6.27.

Answer (score 55):

Just to add my configuration to the mix, I'm using MySQL 5.7.8 which has the same strict sql_mode rules by default.

- I finally figured the following working in my /etc/mysql/my.conf:

  ```
  [mysqld]
  sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
  ```

i.e. dash, not underscore and quotes around the value.

- I have NO other my.conf files other than /etc/mysql/my.conf
- There are some extra config includes being loaded from /etc/mysql/conf.d/ but they are blank.

And that seems to work for me.

Comment: There appears to be a lot of variation of what it is supposed to be, and what actually works, as evidenced by these answers :D sometimes underscore or dash, sometimes quoted. (facepalm)

Comment: For me, I noticed that there were issues parsing when it wasn't under the `[mysqld]` section. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: The server wouldn't even start wihtout me using [mysql]

Comment: Definitely needed the [mysql] in my "mysql.cnf"!

Comment: In my case, I wrote the configuration in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and restart MySQL service using command: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`, and it worked. I'm using MySQL 5.7.26 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 12):

Your server may read a different `my.cnf` than the one you're editing (unless you specified it when starting mysqld).

From the [MySQL Certification Study Guide](http://www.amazon.de/MySQL-Certification-Study-Guide-authoritative/dp/0672328127):

> The search order includes two general option files, `/etc/my.cnf` and
>   `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf`. The second file is used only if the `MYSQL_HOME`
>   environment variable is set. Typically, you seet it to the MySQL
>   installation directory. (The mysqld_safe script attempts to set
>   `MYSQL_HOME` if it is not set before starting the server.)   The
>   option file search order also includes `~/.my.cnf` (that is the home
>   directory). This isn't an especially suitable location for server
>   options. (Normally, you invoke the server as `mysql`, or as `root`
>   with a `--user=mysql` option. The user-specific file read by the
>   server would depend on which login account you invoke it from,
>   possibly leading to inconsistent sets of options being used.)

Another possibility is of course, that your `sql-mode` option gets overwritten further down in the same file. Multiple options have to be separated by `,`  in the same line.

P.S.: And you need the quotes, IIRC. Now that you've tried it without quotes, I'm pretty sure, you're editing the wrong file, since MySQL doesn't start when there's an error in the option file.

P.P.S.: Had a look at my config files again, there it's

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

and it's working.

Comment: We have replication on, and that's defined in this my.cnf file, so this is definitely the configuration that is being used (but I'll check that it's not ovewriting somewhere else. As I mentioned to Riad, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) says to use underscore version and quotes. So if your suggestion is correct, the docs are wrong. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I updated my question with more troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi I have same issue then i updated /etc/my.cnf file but after some days server rewritten my file and create backup of old file. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: @YogeshSaroya MySQL server never writes in that file. If it changed, something else must have changed it, like your package manager or whatever. Please ask this in a separate question.

Answer (score 11):

It should be:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

instead of

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

then restart mysqld service.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that (although I think I did that originally. The syntax is definitely confusing, because the documentation says it should be `sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` with dash not underscore and quotes? `To set the SQL mode at server startup, use the --sql-mode="modes" option on the command line, or sql-mode="modes" in an option file such as my.cnf (Unix operating systems)` --[documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html)

Comment: I updated my question with more troubleshooting. Neither of these options work.

Answer (score 7):

Woks fine for me on ubuntu 16.04.
path: /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf

and paste that

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
sql_mode = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: How it's different from other answers here?

Comment: Its under `[mysqld]`

Answer (score 5):

For me it was a permission problem.

enter:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
```

[Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored.

So try to execute the following, and then restart the server

```
chmod 644 '/etc/mysql/my.cnf'
```

It will give mysql access to read and write to the file.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that I had spaces in between the options on 5.7.20. Removing them so the line looked like

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Answer (score 4):

On **Linux Mint 18** the default config file that has the `sql-mode` option set is located here :

```
/usr/my.cnf
```

And relevant line is:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

So You can set there.

If not sure what config file has such option You can search for it:

```
$ sudo find / -iname "*my.cnf*"
```

And get a list:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf
/usr/my.cnf
/etc/alternatives/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is pretty easy... Searched for it for a while and it turns out that you just have to edit 2 config-files:

- `/usr/my.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

in both files you'll have to add:

```
[mysqld]
...
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

At least, that's what's working for 5.6.24-2+deb.sury.org~precise+2

Comment: We only have one cnf file (not the others) and have edited the /etc/mysql/my.cnf However, the question is, what is the value supposed to be? There are competing values (see syntaxes I mentioned in the question), and for us, none of them work. What syntax did you use?

Comment: Thanks, per the details in my original question, I've tried that already, and when restarting mysql it doesn't stick. But it's good confirmation that this is probably the right setting, and there must be something else preventing these settings from taking effect.

Comment: so you've already searched for other my.cnf in your system and that's really the only one?

Comment: @Ivniebelschuetz yes, it's crazy. Searched many many times in every location, file name search, etc. And in my main /etc/mysql/my.cnf this definition only happens once. It's always possible my testing was incorrect and one of these actually did work, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

For me **both** keys for `sql-mode` worked. Whether I used

```
# dash no quotes
sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

or

```
# underscore no quotes
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

in the `my.ini` file made **no difference** and both were accepted, as far as I could test it.

What actually made a difference was a *missing newline* at the end of the `my.ini` file.

So everyone having problems with this or similar problems with `my.ini`/`my.cnf`: Make sure there is a blank line at the end of the file!

Tested using MySQL 5.7.27.

Answer (score 1):

It was making me crazy also until I realized that the paragraph where the key must be is [mysqld] not [mysql]

So, for 10.3.22-MariaDB-1ubuntu1, my solution is, in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 1):

in Ubuntu 20+ and MySQL 8+
add in

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

or in

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

[mysqld]
sql_mode = ""
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0
```

settings like this, no more working

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mariadb, you have to modify the mariadb.cnf file located in /etc/mysql/conf.d/.

I supposed the stuff is the same for any other my-sql based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I am running WHM 10.2.15-MariaDB.  To permanently disable strict mode first find out which configuration file our installation prefers. For that, we need the binary’s location:

```
$ which mysqld
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Then, we use this path to execute the lookup:

```
$ /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

We can see that the first favored configuration file is one in the root of the etc folder but that there is a second .cnf file hidden  - ~/.my.cnf. Adding the following to the ~/.my.cnf file permanently disabled strict mode for me (needs to be within the mysqld section):

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I found that adding the line to /etc/my.cnf had no effect at all apart from sending me crazy.

Answer (score -2):

[Fixed]
Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Go to: C:\xampp\mysql\bin
open my.ini in notepad and find [mysqld] (line number 27) then after this line(line no 28) just type: skip-grant-tables

save the file and then reload the phpmyadmin page.It worked for me.