# Error in MySQL when setting default value for DATE or DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, console

I'm running MySql Server 5.7.11 and this sentence:

```
updated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

is **not** working. Giving the error:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'updated'
```

But the following:

```
updated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

**just works**.

The same case for DATE.

As a *sidenote*, it is mentioned in the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

even if they also say:

> Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00').

Having also into account the second quote from MySQL documentation, could anyone let me know why it is giving that error?

Comment: Why would you want a default that is obviously meaningless? If the date is unknown then that's exactly what `NULL` is for.

Comment: As a note:  This works in version 5.6 on SQL Fiddle -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02c98.

Comment: @Karlos check the updated answer.

Comment: @TomH The fact that ZERO in a date seems to you meaningless is out the interest of many readers. Obviously, `NULL` is always there as it is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Both of them, seem to me very different. To answer your comment, also out of the scope of this post, and sure of the full website itself.

Comment: @TomH This is a good question to ask the MySQL team :D

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The error is because of the sql mode which can be strict mode as per latest MYSQL 5.7 documentation.

[MySQL Documentation 5.7 says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict):

> Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date:
> If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning.
> If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

**To Check MYSQL mode**

`SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session`

**Disabling STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode**

However to allow the format `0000-00-00 00:00:00`you have to disable STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode in mysql config file or by command

**By command**

`SET sql_mode = '';`

or

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';`

Using the keyword `GLOBAL` requires super previliges and it affects the operations all clients connect from that time on

if above is not working than go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (as per ubuntu) and comment out `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

Also, if you want to permanently set the sql mode at server startup then include `SET sql_mode=''` in `my.cnf` on Linux or MacOS. For windows this has to be done in `my.ini` file.

**Note**

However, strict mode is not enabled by default in MYSQL 5.6. Hence it does not produce the error as per [MYSQL 5.6 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html) which says

> MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode.

**UPDATE**

Regarding the bug matter as said by @Dylan-Su:

I don't think this is a bug - it is the way MYSQL is evolved over the time due to which some things are changed based on further improvement of the product.

However I have another related bug report regarding the `NOW()` function:

[Datetime field does not accept default NOW()](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645)

**Another Useful note** [see [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)]

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table. The following notes first describe automatic initialization and updating for MySQL 5.6.5 and up, then the differences for versions preceding 5.6.5.

**Update Regarding NO_ZERO_DATE**

As of MySQL as of 5.7.4 this mode is deprecated. For previous version you must comment out the respective line in the config file. Refer [MySQL 5.7 documentation on NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

Comment: I had to use `SET sql_mode = '';` and `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';` on Ubuntu 16.04 with MySQL 5.7.24 for it to work.

Answer (score 27):

I got into a situation where the data was mixed between NULL and 0000-00-00 for a date field. But I did not know how to update the '0000-00-00' to NULL, because

```
 update my_table set my_date_field=NULL where my_date_field='0000-00-00'
```

is not allowed any more.
My workaround was quite simple:

```
update my_table set my_date_field=NULL where my_date_field<'0000-01-01'
```

because all the incorrect `my_date_field` values (whether correct dates or not) were from before this date.

Comment: Perfect quick solution.  You could in fact also use `<'0000-01-01'` since it is of course a valid date.

Comment: fastest way, thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I had this error with WAMP 3.0.6 with MySql 5.7.14.

**Solution**:

change line 70 (if your ini file is untouched) in  `c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\my.ini` file from

```
sql-mode= "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
```

to

```
sql-mode="ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
```

and restart all services.

This will disable strict mode. As per the documentation, “strict mode” means a mode with either or both `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` enabled.
The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) says:

> "The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes:
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,
>   NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, and
>   NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION."

Answer (score 14):

First select current session `sql_mode`:

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

Then you will get something like that [default value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-sql-modes.html#faq-mysql-what-default-mode):

> 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

and then set `sql_mode` without `'NO_ZERO_DATE'`:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

If you have grants, you can do it also for `GLOBAL`:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '...';
```

Answer (score 4):

## Config syntax issue

On some versions of MYSQL (tested 5.7.*) under *nix systems you should use this syntax:

```
[mysqld]

sql-mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

## These won't work:

*dash no quotes*

```
sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

*underscore no quotes*

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

*underscore and quotes*

```
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

**A more complete review of config values and sql-mode:**

[How to setup permanent Sql Mode flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849293/how-to-make-sql-mode-no-engine-substitution-permanent-in-mysql-my-cnf)

Answer (score 3):

It works for 5.7.8:

```
mysql> create table t1(updated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show create table t1;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                            |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t1    | CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.8-rc  |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can create a SQLFiddle to recreate your issue.

http://sqlfiddle.com/

***If it works for MySQL 5.6 and 5.7.8, but fails on 5.7.11. Then it probably is a regression bug for 5.7.11.***

Answer (score 3):

Just add the line: `sql_mode = "NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

inside file: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

then `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Works for 5.7.23.

Comment: I would probably suggest  `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` first, and them removing NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, and STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from what it gives you. That way you keep whatever other settings you had enabled. I had a lot more than just those two items set for my sql mode. Don't know what they all do, but I don't want to risk removing them at this point.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem with MySQL Workbench (After applying the solution on the server side) :

Remove SQL_MODE to TRADITIONAL in the preferences panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer it's just for MySQL 5.7:

Best is not really set in blank the sql_mode, instead use in PHP a session variable with:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode= 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

So at least you keep the other default values.

It's crazy that mysql documentation is not clear, you need delete to these default values in sql_mode:

NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE, I understand, but in the future versions this will be discontinued.

STRICT_ALL_TABLES, with  this, before parameters will be ignored, so you need to delete it too.

Finally TRADITIONAL too, but documentation speaks about this parameter: “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column", with this parameter, dates with zero values is not inserted, but without yes.

MySQL is not really organised with these parameters and combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Option combinations for `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64)`.

Doesn't throw:

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` + `NO_ZERO_DATE`

Throws:

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` + `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`

My settings in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Ubuntu:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set global sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a fix as follow:

```
1). On the file "system/library/db/mysqli.php" search and comment the line: 
"$this->connection->query("SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'");"

2) Add the following line above the one you just commented:
// Correction by Added by A.benkorich
$this->connection->query("SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the database and run SQL query:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use following command to change the default date to current_timestamp:-**

```
  ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` CHANGE `post_date` `post_date`  DATETIME NOT
  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**2. Use following command to change the default date to NULL:-**

```
 ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` CHANGE `post_date` `post_date`  DATETIME NOT
 NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

**3. Use following command to change default date for more than 1 column
using single SQL query:-**

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts`  CHANGE `post_date` `post_date` DATETIME NOT NULL 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt` 
DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE `post_modified` 
`post_modified` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE 
`post_modified_gmt` `post_modified_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a new project, tried to add a new column

```
ALTER TABLE prefix_example_table ADD COLUMN stackoverflow decimal(11,3) NOT NULL
```

And got this error

```
#1292 - Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00'
```

For another column which i didn't even tried to add a new data to it, the Column that returned this error had the Default value **'0000-00-00'** for type **Date** .

As @geeksal mentioned

> Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

I have tried for hours thought the problem was related to **PRIVILAGES**

This  saved my hours of work.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Answer (score -1):

In directory xampp/mysql/bin
Open "my.ini" and change line: sql_mode for ->

```
"sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE"

REMOVE "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE"
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please use proper code formatting to improve the legibility of the answer.