# INSERT SELECT with string SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-select-db

i want to copy the content of one column to another column. The copied content should be linked to a string.

```
|  company  |  new_company  |
_____________________________
Google      | The Google Company
```

Here the "The" and "Company" are attached as a string to the content.

I have tried a lot, which is the most meaningful to me looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (copy_into_column)
SELECT CONCAT('The ', copy_from_column, ' Company')
FROM table_name
```

But with this sql i get that error:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'time' at row 1035
```

Of course, I have several columns in my right table, but actually should be disregarded or?

I hope someone has an idea.

Comment: Is `time` defined as `not null`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in mysql when setting default value for DATE or DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime)

Comment: time Null = No, but each entry in the column time has a value

Comment: maybe you have to reformat your datetime from string to date with `STR_TO_DATE('18,05,2009','%d,%m,%Y');  ` ?

Comment: i cant change the type of fields or even the date. it is a database with tousend of entrys. and it is already a finish script behind it. is there a way to ignore these columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you looking for update statement?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET copycol = CONCAT('The ', copy_from_column, ' Company')
```

### About the error that you get:

You have a timestamp field that apparently is required. from the code you've shared, I see that you are inserting new rows into DB, where I guess you don't fill the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is another column named `time` that does not accept null values. You can try inserting current time instead, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (copy_into_column, time)
    SELECT CONCAT('The ', copy_from_column, ' Company'), NOW()
    FROM table_name;
```