# Is it possible to resrtict the hours in laravel faker->dateTimeBetween? If so, how?

Tags: php, laravel, faker

So I'm using faker to seed the database with data for testing. Right now, when I use `'created_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-5 years', '-3 days')` it breaks and says

`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-25 02:45:11' for column`

I've looked it up and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49610684/13698713),

This is most likely a timezone conversion error on the day of standard-time to daylight-time switchover. **The hour from 0200 to just before 0300 does not exist.**

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? For example, specifying that the dateTimeBetween can only select hours between 6 and 18?

*Edit #1:* This mostly happens when I try to seed with 10k+ data (for testing speed, cache, and other stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to add in an extra step to convert it to a DateTime or Carbon object:

```
'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-5 years', '-3 days'))->toDateTimeString()
```

This will force the faker date into a Carbon instance, which should convert the date properly. For instance, if I do

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2018-03-11 02:45:11');
```

while in a US Eastern timezone, the date becomes `2018-03-11 03:45:11.0 America/New_York (-04:00)`

Also make sure that Laravel and MySQL are on the same timezone (or use Carbon to convert the timezone), or use UTC.

Comment: I've tried it like that just now and it still runs into the same problem, since it can get a non-existing date (because the hour given does not exist as I mentioned):
**The hour from 0200 to just before 0300 does not exist.**
`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-25 02:36:38' for column 'laravel'.'posts'.'created_at'`

Comment: Double-check the timezones for Laravel and for your database. I wonder if they aren't the same, so Laravel thinks it's okay, but MySQL doesnt

Comment: Oh true, I forgot it's set to UTC by default. Changing the timezone fixes the problem, even without the Carbon or other reformats. Thank you! (submit the timezone-checking comment as an answer so I can accept it)

Comment: I've added the comment