# MySQL 5.7: Invalid default value for 'event_end_date'

Tags: mysql

We are migrating our application from `MySQL 5.5` to `5.7`. As the default value `0000-00-00` is not allowed anymore for date fields in `MySQL 5.7` in strict mode, I would like to change the default value to `NULL`.

The concerned fields are defined as follows:

```
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| event_start_date | date                 | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| event_end_date   | date                 | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

When I try to execute the following `ALTER` query:

```
ALTER TABLE events CHANGE event_start_date event_start_date date DEFAULT NULL;    
ALTER TABLE events CHANGE event_end_date event_end_date date DEFAULT NULL;
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid default value for 'event_end_date'
```

I know it would be possible to disable strict mode, but that is not the solution I am looking for. Strangely enough the same query worked for an other table.

Anyone has an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Post the table stucture `SHOW CREATE TABLE events`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in MySQL when setting default value for DATE or DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens already in your query on the first line. There you are trying to change the column `event_start_date`, the error message however is for column `event_end_date`. You need to change both columns with a single query in order to avoid this error:

```
ALTER TABLE events CHANGE event_start_date event_start_date date DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE event_end_date event_end_date date DEFAULT NULL;
```

It probably worked with your other table because you only had one column of type `date`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new strict mode in MySQL 5.7. The default SQL_MODE in MySQL 5.7 is:
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

The best way is to change the schema as @cansik suggested. 
You can also remove NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE from sql_mode (not recommended but can be temporary workaround)

set global sql_mode="... choose which modes you need ... "