# Invalid Default value (Time Stamp) issue in Database(SQL)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm try to create table as below, but get error:

> Invalid default value for 'updated_at'

I don't know what to do...what's wrong in query.

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `body` text NOT NULL,
 `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime ?

Comment: I would try wrapping the literal date with a conversion to a timestamp value.

Comment: Thanks....Now its working after i disabled my SQL mode.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According SQL standard '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is not valid value for timestamp field. You should to use `NULL` as default value fro `updated_at` column.

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `body` text NOT NULL,
 `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Also `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` part is not relevant for `created_at` field, but relevant for `updated_at`