# mysql return 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for null datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime

In my one of the MySQL tables have one column cancelled_dts that is of type DateTime, which accepts null value and default set as "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

When I execute a query like this "SELECT * FROM tablename where cancelled_dts IS NULL"
it's returning the rows which contain "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

I tried using the following query on the same database

```
select if('0000-00-00 00:00:00' != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'Not Same', 'Same'),
if('0000-00-00 00:00:00' IS NULL, 'NULL', 'NOT NULL'),
if('0000-00-00 00:00:00' IS NOT NULL, 'NOT NULL', 'NULL')
```

to check the behaviour and it gave output as "Same", "NOT NULL" and "NOT NULL" for the statements.

Comment: Can you give the table definition, and some example data?

Comment: In your `if` condition you operate with ***strings***.  So it has nothing to do with empty ***dates***.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
  --
  `cancelled_dts` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'cancelled date and time',
  --
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53233 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

Comment: @BartFriederichs Added schema above cant share all the columns

Answer (score 0):

`'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` is invalid DateTime value in mysql,
`DateTime.MinValue` is `0001-01-01 00:00:00`, but the minimum supported value for a `DATETIME` column is `1000-01-01 00:00:00` In many versions of MySQL Server

Comment: that is false, you can set this when you allow NULL in your sql mode

Comment: Please check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html before. It may allow you to add this value according to the GUI you are using to deal with mysql. So it may convert the '0000-....' value to null before store it to the table.

Comment: I don't need to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime

Comment: the data is already there from legacy database