# SQLAlchemy reads from mysql/mariadb database 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and null with datetime/timestamp data type values as the same

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, default

When I try to read data from table in one database(using Python, sqlalchemy or pandas to make some manipulations with data) and send this data to the same table in another database (with the same shema of table) values with the type **datetime/timestamp** in mysql which are equal to **0000-00-00 00:00:00** value or **NULL** (so this column can be **NULL**, some date(include 0000-00-00 00:00:00)), in Python they have the same value as **None**(if it's just sqlalchemy), or **NaT**(if we read to pandas dataframe).
How can I save this values, and send to another table valid data(if was 0000-00-00 00:00:00, send **0000-00-00 00:00:00**, if was NULL send **NULL**)

example shema of a table:

```
create table some_table
(
    userid           int auto_increment,
    username         varchar(255)        not null,
    email            varchar(255)        not null,
    lastLogin_Date   datetime            null,
    primary key (userid)
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Data in MYSQL

**column:**

**lastLogin_Date**

null

0000-00-00 00:00:00

null

null

null

How this data reads python sqlalchemy -

Output if sqlalchemy:
[(None,), (None,), (None,), (None,), (None,)]

Output pandas:

0 NaT

1 NaT

2 NaT

3 NaT

4 NaT

5 NaT

How I make it in Python,so if just use sqlalchemy we will get as above None (also as I know under the hood in pandas sqlalchemy):

```
engine3 = create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://' + 'root' + ':' + 'root' + 
    '@localhost:' + '3306' + '/' + 'testdb',
    echo=False)

for chunk_dataframe in pd.read_sql(
        "SELECT * FROM table_name", engine3, chunksize=10000):
    pass
```

After the data is returned to mysql with the method df.to_sql(...), instead of 0000-00-00 00:00:00, it will be NULL, respectively, how to save the original values?

Comment: You might try the `SET sql_mode = '';` trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374690/2144390)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried, but it doesn't help