# sql_mode how to set several values by executing

Tags: mysql

I have tried putting this in my cnf files but nothing seems to work and I am running short on time, restarting MySQL all the time trying and it is just not working. I don't want to mess anything up and I wonder how to execute this in SQL statement:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sql-mode="NO\_ENGINE\_SUBSTITUTION" permanent in MySQL my.cnf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849293/how-to-make-sql-mode-no-engine-substitution-permanent-in-mysql-my-cnf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer if someones interested

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

and to see if it did any effects

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```