# MYSQL sql_mode Keeps reseting after mysql restart

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, sql-mode

Setup

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.38, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

MYSQL Keeps reseting my **sql_mode** and so my website is not working well.

The MySQL message is the following

```
Expression #18 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'testdevnew.f.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

What I do till now is from terminal to connect inside mysql with the command

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and run the following commands

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

mysql> set session sql_mode='NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

And the error is gone, but for a couple of days.. lets say that we restart mysql server and the above settings are gone.

Also tried to change the following files with the sql_mode that i would like to load after mysql restart.

File list

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

(I've also tried with value in quotes)

Then restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

But the setting is not affecting mysql restart and I keep getting the error mentioned above.

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

prints the following

```
sql-mode                                                     NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might have other `my.cnf` files being referenced by mysqld.

Also make sure those MySQL configuration files are owned by a mysql user and has read/write permission. Once restarted, verify using the code below whether your sql-mode configuration is loaded properly.

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

This thread, [How to make sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" permanent in MySQL my.cnf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849293/how-to-make-sql-mode-no-engine-substitution-permanent-in-mysql-my-cnf) has all the required steps to help you troubleshoot this issue.